# CSS background image not expanding

Tags: css

I am using a 10x400 px image as my background image and the css is this:

```
body {
    background-image:url('bg1.png');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
```

In chrome the image is expanding to the full height of the screen in chrome but not in firefox or IE. Help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `min-height` to `html`. 
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/qQqTx/3/)

```
html{
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    background-image: url('path_to_img.png');
    text-align: center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Don't think `background-repeat: repeat-x` will be needed if `background-size: 100% 100%` is used.

Comment: It worked after i removed body from the min height part. otherwise for chrome it was giving me a scrollbar as the screen increased

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following to make it repeat vertically and horizontally.

```
background-repeat: repeat
```

[Mozilla Documentation on CSS background-repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-repeat)

Comment: I dont want it to repeat along the height since it has a gradient and will giva a bad striated look